# Visual studio "out of memory" and wont let me save or compile

Tags: memory, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, vb.net

I've been sitting here in frustration for hours trying to fix this or find an answer.

So I have a fairly large project (7 megabyte exe due to the amount of assets) that i'm trying to work on. But it seems that after a few hours of working on it I go to compile or save and visual studio pops up a message saying i'm "out of memory" (Event though a good 80% of the time visual studio is below 1gb ram usage and I have plenty of free RAM and HDD space). I've tried on both 2015 and 2017 and both have the exact same issues. I was able to manually fix it by using RAMMap to clear the processes working memory and I would be able to work for a good half an hour more and id keep doing it every time it popped up. But eventually no matter how many times I tried this workaround I found stopped working. So I attempted to restart VS (As the changes I made before the last save were minor). And now I have an error with the windows media player library and the designer wont launch. So I remove the library and now I cant re import it again.

I apologize for the long paragraph But my project is in a massive mess right now and I need to get it sorted. I've tried asking around and cant seem to find a single answer except for "update visual studio" (Which I've tried) I can compile the exe but its missing windows media player components and I cant edit the form. (I am programming in VB.net using winforms). So now I have 2 problems as I have to fix the RAM issue and recover my project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

EDIT: Managed to fix the library issues but still have issues with out of memory

Comment: If you want to only compile the project you may use `msbuild` command. Also check if any faulty extension in VS.